# Não consigo fazer um campo do formulário ser enviado para o e-mail com phpmailer

Tags: php, html5

Tenho um formulário que nele tem um campo com um (select one menu) nele existe algumas opcões onde o usuário deve escolher apenas uma e seleciona-la  esse formulário envia as informações para meu e-mail essa funcionalidade já esta funcionando porem não consigo fazer com que este campo apareça no e-mail também segue meu código.

```
    <div id="formulario">
        <form action="email.php" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" name="Nome" id="nome" placeholder="  Digite seu nome" required name=nome ></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="  Digite seu Email" required name=email></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="Nickname" placeholder="  Digite seu Nickname" required name=nickname></li>
                <li>
                    <select name="Games">
                        <option value ="the-elder" selected>  --- Selecione um jogo ---</option>
                        <option value ="the-elder">The Elder Scrols Online</option>
                        <option value ="archage">ArcheAge</option>
                        <option value ="worlofwarcraft">World of War Craft </option>
                        <option value ="forsaken">Forsaken World</option>
                        <option value ="leagueoflegends">League of Legends</option>
                        <option value ="dota">Dota 2</option>
                        <option value ="smite">Smite</option>
                        <option value ="warface">Warface</option>
                        <option value ="cs">CS-GO</option>
                        <option value ="bf">Battle Field</option>
                        <option value ="cod">Call of Dutty</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li><textarea placeholder="  Mensagem" name="Mensagem" required name=mensagem></textarea></li>
                <li><input type=submit value="Enviar" id="enviar" name="Enviar"/></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
```

O php lembrado que ele esta em um arquivo separado e estou usando o phpmailer:

```
<?php
$Nome       = $_POST["Nome"];   // Pega o valor do campo Nome
$Nickname       = $_POST["Nickname"];   // Pega o valor do campo Telefone
$Email      = $_POST["Email"];  // Pega o valor do campo Email
$Mensagem   = $_POST["Mensagem"];   // Pega os valores do campo Mensagemgames
$Games  = $_POST["Games"];  // Pega os valores do campo Mensagemgames


// Variável que junta os valores acima e monta o corpo do email

$Vai        = "Nome: $Nome\n\nE-mail: $Email\n\nNicknamer: $Nickname\n\nMensagem: $Mensagem\n";

require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

define('GUSER', 'felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com');   // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', 'lalala123');        // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 465;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}

// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 

 if (smtpmailer('felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com', 'felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com', 'felipe', 'Recrutamento Nova Era', $Vai)) {

    Header("location:obrigado.html"); // Redireciona para uma página de obrigado.

}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
?>
```

OBS:o campo do formulário que também quero que aparece no e-mail e não estou conseguindo seria esse:

```
<li>
  <select name="Games">
     <option value ="the-elder" selected>  --- Selecione um jogo ---</option>
     <option value ="the-elder">The Elder Scrols Online</option>
     <option value ="archage">ArcheAge</option>
     <option value ="worlofwarcraft">World of War Craft </option>
     <option value ="forsaken">Forsaken World</option>
     <option value ="leagueoflegends">League of Legends</option>
     <option value ="dota">Dota 2</option>
     <option value ="smite">Smite</option>
     <option value ="warface">Warface</option>
     <option value ="cs">CS-GO</option>
     <option value ="bf">Battle Field</option>
     <option value ="cod">Call of Dutty</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Comment: Vc não está concatenando `$Games` em `$Vai`

Comment: @Lucas olaaa amigo posta ai isso como resposta pa eu marcar como aceita porque funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está concatenando `$Games` em `$Vai`. É só fazer assim:

```
$Vai = "Nome: $Nome\n\nE-mail: $Email\n\nNicknamer: $Nickname\n\nGame: $Games\n\nMensagem: $Mensagem\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Seus input tem dois atributos `name` como este `textarea`

```
<textarea placeholder="  Mensagem" name="Mensagem" required name=mensagem></textarea>
```

Se entendi bem você quer enviar um  campo select junto com seu email, Adicione esta linha antes de enviar o email:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

e concatene seu `select` ao corpo do email:

```
$vai .= "<select name="Games"></select>";
```